# How to get multiple repeated using Joins?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, merge, sql-server-2012

I have a temp table with the following structure:

```
 StudentID  VALUE
   1          5
   2          NULL
```

and need to map the values from it to the table below:

```
 StudentID  DEPT
    1        1
    1        2
    2        3 
    2        4
```

So the output should be like this:

```
StudentID  DEPT VALUE
  1        1     5
  1        2     5
  2        3     NULL
  2        4     NULL
```

Do I need to use join or merge my table consisits of million record?
I have tried using joins but i am not getting exact what i need?

Comment: This can be made with simple inner join. Could you post what have you try to check if you are doing everything right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a JOIN. like this:

```
SELECT S.StudentId, S.Dept, V.Value
FROM Student AS S
JOIN #TEMP AS V
  ON V.StudentId = S.StudentId
ORDER BY V.StudentId
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT table2.StudentID
      ,table2.DEPT
      ,#TEMP.Value
FROM table2
LEFT JOIN #TEMP
    ON table2.StudentID = #TEMP.StudentID
```

Comment: LEFT  JOIN isn't necessary, his #TEMP should have a row for all students, the example shows that and he never mentions needing that.

Comment: He did not state directly that the temp table would have all student IDs, and the query would give the same result.  No need to downvote

Comment: on SO you answer the question.  Your answer makes it look like a LEFT JOIN is necessary and it is not.  Unless the OP specifies that then answering his question given the FACTS is what your answer should do.